# pod has unbound intermediate access persistnt volumeclaim:PVC

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-aks, persistent-volumes

I have created the persistent volume and define the some access modes as shown below
I am having the setup like persistent volume and persistent volume claim , So created the deployment for the below scripts

pv scipt

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PV
metadata:
  name: pv_name
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /mnt/disks/ssd1
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - node1
```

PVC script

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PVC
metadata:
  name: PVC_name
spec:
  volumeName: PVC_demo-name
  storageClassName: local-storage
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

After deploying when i check my volume status it is pending and when i describe my logs it is showing the below error
 `Warning  FailedScheduling  <unknown>  default-scheduler  running <VolumeBinding> filter plugin for pod <Pod_name>: pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims`

when check some realted [Github link](https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/issues/2362) it is showing related grafana, but i am not using any grafan configuration
What this error mean, any idea or help?

What this error mean, am i need to add any script to resolve this issue, any idea or help?

Comment: You tagged this with a couple of Azure-related tags.  Especially in a cloud environment, I wouldn't expect to need to manually create the PersistentVolume; the cluster should be able to do that on its own.  You may also want a StatefulSet with a PersistentVolumeClaim template, rather than creating the PVC yourself.

Comment: @user00088 is the access modes are same for both PV and PVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I tried to reproduce the same issue in my environment and got the below results*
I have created the deployment for persistent volume and volume claim

> We will get this error if the both access modes are different

When I check my status it is pending

[image]

I use the below command and got the same error(warning)

[image]

While creating the PV and PVC I have defined the two access modes one is for ReadWriteOnce and ReadWriteMany

Because of these different accesses Kubernetes cluster will end up with this error

To resolve this issue I have deleted the the entire persistent volumes and created again with the same access mode

***PV script:***

```
volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
```

***PVC script:***

```
 volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
```

I have recreated the deployment and when I check my status its bound got success

```
kubectl apply/create -f filename
    kubectl get pvc
```

[image]

When I describe my logs I am not getting any error as shown below

[image]